# Running .vue files with Syntax Highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, plugins, frontend, ide

I'm currently working on a Vue.js project using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, and I'm looking to set up my environment to properly support .vue files with syntax highlighting and other essential features. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to find a dedicated "Vue.js" plugin in the IntelliJ Marketplace.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Installed Node.js and used Vue CLI to create a new Vue.js project.
- Opened the project in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

However, when working with .vue files, I'm not getting the expected syntax highlighting or specialized support for Vue.js-related code.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to configure IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition to properly support .vue files? Are there any recommended plugins, settings, or steps I should follow to achieve this?

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance or insights from those who have successfully set up Vue.js development in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The dedicated [Vue.js](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js) plugin is only available in IDEA Ultimate, it's not possible to make it work in the Community edition that supports neither JavaScript nor frameworks. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce

Answer (score 0):

Vue support is available in paid IDE versions only (Intellij IDEA Ultimate, WebStrom, PhpStorm, etc.).

You can get some syntax highlighting for `*.vue` files via [TextMate Bundles](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7221-textmate-bundles) plugin which is built-in in all modern JetBrains IDEs. There is a [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tutorial-using-textmate-bundles.html) of using it.

Another option that isn't covered in the tutorial is to reuse TextMate grammar bundled in a VSCode extension:

1. Call `Install VSCode Plugin...` action (you can search for available actions via [Find Action](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/presenting/find-action/) dialog).
2. Search for `vue` (just type `vue`) in the appeared list of extensions.
3. Select one of the extensions to install (there are few of them but I don't know which one is the best).

You can manage installed bundles in `Settings > Editor > TextMate Bundles`.

Before-after example (*seanwash/vue* extension is used):
[image: Before-after]